# MS SQL 2008 R2, security and auditing

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security, audit

I have an 2008R2 SQL Server.
There are a few AD groups added to the logins. 
Each group must have some permissions (and only these permissions if possible).
Can someone help me with a few questions:

- Can I restrict permissions for one of the groups only to view users and their permissions? And if we have only AD groups in Login section - executing stored procedures like **xp_logininfo 'domain\group' , members** is the only one way to show users in this group?
- All users are getting the "public" role by default. I've excluded all permissions from the permission section in the role properties, but users with this role are still able to see system databases. Can I deny this?